# Openstack volume service list showing down

Tags: openstack, openstack-cinder

I am configuring second storage node in `Openstack XENA` in **Ubuntu 20.04**. But after **restarting** `cinder-volume` services my old cinder storage node also **goes down**. But all services are properly running with no error found in any logs.

Controller Node:

```
# openstack volume service list
+------------------+-----------------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
| Binary           | Host            | Zone | Status  | State | Updated At                 |
+------------------+-----------------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
| cinder-scheduler | controller      | nova | enabled | up    | 2022-03-08T15:40:43.000000 |
| cinder-volume    | compute2@lvm    | nova | enabled | down  | 2022-03-08T15:39:42.000000 |
| cinder-volume    | compute3@lvm    | nova | enabled | down  | 2022-03-08T15:39:38.000000 |
| cinder-volume    | compute1@lvm    | nova | enabled | down  | 2022-03-08T15:39:36.000000 |
| cinder-volume    | backupopen1@lvm | nova | enabled | down  | 2022-03-08T15:39:43.000000 |
+------------------+-----------------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
```

Controller **cinder-scheduler** logs:

```
# tail -f /var/log/cinder/cinder-scheduler.log
2022-03-08 12:40:43.138 2531384 WARNING cinder.scheduler.host_manager [req-b9c886c5-4064-4b65-9a23-f93226d5d414 - - - - -] volume service is down. (host: backupopen1@lvm)
2022-03-08 12:42:12.661 2531384 INFO cinder.message.api [req-582b7c56-1a72-4c18-879c-fcf35d49dddb - - - - -] Deleted 0 expired messages.
2022-03-08 15:27:29.005 2531384 WARNING cinder.scheduler.host_manager [req-7dd2bcfd-1f8a-4e27-86eb-abb773a7a4a1 86dbb0d4f02e42fbac58934b1b87e025 e8f71e77c0874cedbc4de22f1bd971bc - - -] volume service is down. (host: compute2@lvm)
2022-03-08 15:27:29.006 2531384 WARNING cinder.scheduler.host_manager [req-7dd2bcfd-1f8a-4e27-86eb-abb773a7a4a1 86dbb0d4f02e42fbac58934b1b87e025 e8f71e77c0874cedbc4de22f1bd971bc - - -] volume service is down. (host: compute3@lvm)
2022-03-08 15:27:29.006 2531384 WARNING cinder.scheduler.host_manager [req-7dd2bcfd-1f8a-4e27-86eb-abb773a7a4a1 86dbb0d4f02e42fbac58934b1b87e025 e8f71e77c0874cedbc4de22f1bd971bc - - -] volume service is down. (host: compute1@lvm)
2022-03-08 15:27:29.006 2531384 WARNING cinder.scheduler.host_manager [req-7dd2bcfd-1f8a-4e27-86eb-abb773a7a4a1 86dbb0d4f02e42fbac58934b1b87e025 e8f71e77c0874cedbc4de22f1bd971bc - - -] volume service is down. (host: backupopen1@lvm)
```

The `backupopen1` logs:

```
# tail -f /var/log/cinder/cinder-volume.log
2022-03-08 14:10:06.137 25148 INFO cinder.service [-] Starting cinder-volume node (version 19.0.0)
2022-03-08 14:10:06.152 25148 INFO cinder.volume.manager [req-3b929bf1-6053-4594-b7e6-8abf423fe62d - - - - -] Starting volume driver LVMVolumeDriver (3.0.0)
2022-03-08 14:10:08.319 25148 INFO cinder.volume.drivers.lvm [req-3b929bf1-6053-4594-b7e6-8abf423fe62d - - - - -] Enabling LVM thin provisioning by default because a thin pool exists.
2022-03-08 14:10:09.525 25148 INFO cinder.volume.driver [req-3b929bf1-6053-4594-b7e6-8abf423fe62d - - - - -] Driver hasn't implemented _init_vendor_properties()
2022-03-08 14:10:09.571 25148 INFO cinder.keymgr.migration [req-98b859d1-ea25-41fb-a225-3c93403d4e94 - - - - -] Not migrating encryption keys because the ConfKeyManager's fixed_key is not in use.
2022-03-08 14:10:10.505 25148 INFO cinder.volume.manager [req-3b929bf1-6053-4594-b7e6-8abf423fe62d - - - - -] Driver initialization completed successfully.
2022-03-08 14:10:10.511 25148 INFO cinder.manager [req-3b929bf1-6053-4594-b7e6-8abf423fe62d - - - - -] Initiating service 6 cleanup
2022-03-08 14:10:10.514 25148 INFO cinder.manager [req-3b929bf1-6053-4594-b7e6-8abf423fe62d - - - - -] Service 6 cleanup completed.
2022-03-08 14:10:10.558 25148 INFO cinder.volume.manager [req-3b929bf1-6053-4594-b7e6-8abf423fe62d - - - - -] Initializing RPC dependent components of volume driver LVMVolumeDriver (3.0.0)
2022-03-08 14:10:11.510 25148 INFO cinder.volume.manager [req-3b929bf1-6053-4594-b7e6-8abf423fe62d - - - - -] Driver post RPC initialization completed successfully.
```

The `openstack volume service list` output:

```
# openstack volume service list
+------------------+-----------------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
| Binary           | Host            | Zone | Status  | State | Updated At                 |
+------------------+-----------------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
| cinder-scheduler | controller      | nova | enabled | up    | 2022-03-08T15:57:23.000000 |
| cinder-volume    | compute2@lvm    | nova | enabled | down  | 2022-03-08T15:56:22.000000 |
| cinder-volume    | compute3@lvm    | nova | enabled | down  | 2022-03-08T15:56:18.000000 |
| cinder-volume    | compute1@lvm    | nova | enabled | down  | 2022-03-08T15:56:17.000000 |
| cinder-volume    | backupopen1@lvm | nova | enabled | down  | 2022-03-08T15:56:20.000000 |
+------------------+-----------------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Is this still an issue or did you resolve it?